# JavaScript: How to return an outer function inside an asynchronous inner function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, closures

I know I can use an external variable to identify some status the outer function needs to do with. But consider this: If the inner function is asynchronous? The outer function will not wait for the variable of inner function will change, so how can I return the outer function now?

```
function outer() {
    var flag = true;
    // For example, a jquery-like ajax call
    $.ajax({
        // Some settings
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Here I want to return outer()
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

So as you can see, if I use `flag` as the return value, `outer()` will very likely return true because the ajax call may take a long time. And for the same reason, I don't want to set `async: false` because that will stop the page reaction.

Comment: That's not possible with async flows, I'd suggest you add a callback-method as parameter to `outer(cb)` which you call when the ajax request is complete.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was thinking wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `outer` function will return immediately, so you will always get `true` as `flag`'s value. In order to get the right value, you need to let the async function do its job and get back to you when it is ready. Consider this:

```
function outer(cb) {
    var flag = true;
    // For example, a jquery-like ajax call
    $.ajax({
        // Some settings
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Here I want to return outer()
            flag = false;
            cb(flag);
        },
        success: function () {
            flag = true; // or whatever value you need.
            cb(flag);
        }
    });
}

function callback(flag) {
    // this function will be called after the ajax is complete.
    // real value of flag variable will be available here
    console.log(flag);
}
outer(callback);
```

You pass a function as a parameter to outer function, and it calls that function when ajax is complete with the value you need as a parameter. This way you will get the real result.

Comment: Thank you, but I actually need to return it immediately. Now I realize that it's just the same as `async: false`. So I'll have find some other ways.